# Is there a way I can input a period for a time frame and have it change to a colon (Excel)

Tags: excel

I am just looking for a workaround to solve this issue. It's just so me and my colleagues have a simpler way of inputting time.

It is currently being used on a sheet in house, but no one knows how it works.

I would appreciate if anyone has the solution to my issue.

Would like the input of e.g. 8.00 to be changed to 8:00

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure this is strictly possible.  As it stands, Excel will convert 8.00 to 8 unless you put a single tick in front of it, such as `'8.00`, which makes it into a string. While the string can certainly be converted into what you want, if the goal is to save a keystroke, I'm not sure that this will help.

Comment: In what kind of environment is typing 8.00 easier than 8:00?

Comment: Its just that we use a lot of time data for our job. And with the number pad having numbers and a period on there, it is really simple to do. But like I said prior, someone has made a sheet that we use on a day-to-day basis that uses this format. Inputting 7.45 will auto change to 07:45. The issue is that they no longer work with us and they did not  pass over the password.

Comment: Ah, I *think* I understand now.

Comment: Use a worksheet_change to convert any number inputed to a column (or columns) to time or break the password (it isn't that hard).

Comment: How would this be done? Apologies for this question, just any help is welcomed

Comment: If you have a sheet that already has this working, go to the code for that sheet, Google will have many examples on how to find the worksheet code.  Then you can look for `Worksheet_Change` event and it will show you how it was done.

Answer (score 0):

If you type your number into `A1`, you can get your reformatted answer using

`=TIME(A1-MOD(A1,1),MOD(A1*100,100),0)`

Comment: That is a nice workaround, thank you. Would you happen to know if this can be done through formatting a cell, as it would be easier if you can just input 7.00 and it change in the cell automatically to 7:00.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do that outside of VBA.